# mysql count is counting all records instead of filtered count with IN statement

Tags: php, mysql

Im just fiddling around with some sql and trying to get the desired results but I'm just not quite getting what I want. I have a products table and a product_filters table which have a relationship and the product_filters table is related to the filter_values table. In my sql example it prints out the results but it I can't seem to just get count of the products at the top level it prints out 3 instead of 2

here is an example ot the [result set](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9125/81)
and here is the example of the [count](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9125/82)

So what I want is to get the accurate count of 2 products

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
    (SELECT x.product_id,x.department_id,x.title, pi.image_medium
        FROM products x      
        INNER JOIN product_images pi on pi.product_id = x.product_id
     WHERE x.department_id = 3
    )p
INNER JOIN product_filters pf on pf.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN filters f on f.filter_id = pf.filter_id
RIGHT JOIN filter_values fv on fv.filter_value_id = pf.filter_value_id
WHERE p.department_id = 3  AND pf.filter_value_id IN(1,3)
```

Comment: Your "result set" query has a `GROUP BY` that isn't in the "enter link description here" query.

Comment: When you take that out, the second fiddle has two rows for Kindle Fire, so there are 3 total results, which matches the count query.

Comment: Could you just show me what my sql should look like. I checked my statement in the count example and it doesn't have a group by clause. The code above show it without the group by I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `SELECT COUNT(*)` to `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id)`

If you want to see the result set that's being counted, replace `COUNT(*)` with `*`. This results in 2 rows for Samsung Tablet 2, because it has two `product_filters` rows that match the `WHERE` clause.